I can't extract json field using Python
I know this has come up many times but having tried various things from several posts I'm still stuck. The problem is that the JSON file seems more complicated than most and my code (that works on simpler API responses) won't run.
My code is:
response = requests.get(grid_url)
grid_data = json.loads(response.text)  
print (grid_data)
coal = grid_data["data"]["generationmix"]["fuel"]["coal"]
print("coal=" + coal)

consol output is:
{u'data': [{u'dnoregion': u'England', u'shortname': u'England', u'regionid': 15, u'data': [{u'to': u'2024-11-25T19:00Z', u'intensity': {u'index': u'moderate', u'forecast': 144}, u'from': u'2024-11-25T18:30Z', u'generationmix': [{u'fuel': u'biomass', u'perc': 8.8}, {u'fuel': u'coal', u'perc': 0}, {u'fuel': u'imports', u'perc': 10.3}, {u'fuel': u'gas', u'perc': 29}, {u'fuel': u'nuclear', u'perc': 7.3}, {u'fuel': u'other', u'perc': 0}, {u'fuel': u'hydro', u'perc': 1.8}, {u'fuel': u'solar', u'perc': 0}, {u'fuel': u'wind', u'perc': 42.7}]}]}]}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 153, in <module>
    coal = grid_data["data"]["generationmix"]["fuel"]["coal"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

thanks!

{ are dictionaries which you can access by the key (string) and [ are lists which you access by integer indexes,

I disagree to the proposed edit, because the output will not be formatted JSON, it is unformatted JSON.

@ThomasWeller This is a good point, thanks for the suggestion.

As your data contains lists around the dicts, you need to include the list indexes:
fuels = grid_data["data"][0]["data"][0]["generationmix"]
for fuel in fuels:
    if fuel["fuel"] == "coal":
        print(fuel)
        print(fuel['perc'])

Out:
{'fuel': 'coal', 'perc': 0}
0


Beat me by 5 minutes, which I needed to fix the messed up JSON :-D

@ThomasWeller: I just did not comment :)

Many thanks for the extra code, that's got me moving forward at last! Will try to get my head around nested dict & lists !
